# Assignement in matrixes using double indexes

Tags: julia

I can't figure out how to obtain this behavior:

From this matrix:

```
julia> a = [1 1 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 2]
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1  1
 1  1  1
 1  1  2
```

I want to change all the 1s to 5s but only in the last row.

What I did is `a[3, :][a[3, :] .== 1] .= 5` but the value of a isn't changed.

I've noticed that with:

```
foo[foo .== 1] .= 5
a[3,  :] = foo
```

It works, but I'm trying to reduce allocations and this should be removed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `@view` and `replace!`:

```
julia> a = [1 1 1
            1 1 1
            1 1 2]
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1  1
 1  1  1
 1  1  2

julia> replace!(@view(a[end, :]), 1 => 5)
3-element view(::Array{Int64,2}, 3, :) with eltype Int64:
 5
 5
 2

julia> a
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1  1
 1  1  1
 5  5  2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is
`a[3, :][a[3, :] .== 1] .= 5`
is  the same as `getindex(a, 3, :)[a[3, :] .== 1] .=5`

`getindex` returns a copy of that part of `a`
You are mutating the copy, not the original `a`

You want to use a `view`
`view(a, 3, :)[a[3, :] .== 1] .=5`

You can also do this with the `@view` or `@views` macro.